# Is there a way to create a user-defined-literal from `std::initializer_list`?

Tags: c++, literals, initializer-list

Just like in the topic: Is there a way to create a user-defined-literal from `std::initializer_list`?

I am trying to do something like that:

```
template <typename T> inline
std::initializer_list<T> const & operator "" _lit(std::initializer_list<T> const & list)
{
    return std::move(list); // I am not sure, but this line might cause undefined behavior... well I'll think about it latter...
}

int main()
{
    { 10, 20, 30, 40 }_lit // Error: identifier '_lit' is undefined;

    return 0;
}
```

But it seems compiler doesn't understand that I am trying to call `operator""_lit({10, 20, 30, 40});` Is there any way to fix it?

---

**EDIT:** 

I am sorry, it turns out this is just another example of XY problem ... 
Let me elaborate

I am trying to "expand" current C++ syntax (it's a fun little project...)

The main idea is to simplify this:

```
if ((val_1 == value) && (val_2 == value) && (val_3 == value)) { /* ... */ }
```

into somehting along the lines:

```
if (std::initializer_list<T>{val_1, val_2, val_3} == value)
```

ofc I am providing an additional operator:

```
template <typename T> inline
bool operator==(std::initializer_list<T> const & list, T const & ref)
{
    for (auto const & element : list)
    {
        if (element == ref) { /* Do nothing. */ }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Everything would be fine and nice, but I dislike the need to type `std::initializer_list<T>` in front of a curly bracket... Otherwise, the compiler chooses the default version of `operator==()` and I get a compilation error...

Literals come here as an idea to change `if (std::initializer_list<T>{val_1, val_2, val_3} == value)` into `if ({val_1, val_2, val_3}_lit == value)`

Comment: No.  Sounds like an XY problem. What is the use case for this?

Comment: Every form of UDL is listed in cppreference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal . This form isn't listed. Thus, it's not allowed. If you really wanted to be sure, you could check the standard itself

Comment: @NathanOliver I am trying to "expand" current C++ syntax (it's a fun little project...) The main idea is to simplify this: `if ((val_1 == value) && (val_2 == value) && (val_3 == value))` into this: `if (std::initializer_list<T>{val_1, val_2, val_3} == value)` (ofc with an overloaded operator: `bool operator==(std::initializer_list<T> const & list, T const & ref)`)... I want to ommit the part in which i need to type `std::initializer_list<T>` and i figured out that i can change it into a custom-literal

Comment: @cukier9a7b5 Don't overload operators for types you do not own. You should use your own type, not `std::initializer_list`. Aside from that, if you use a ranges library, you could get `if (all_of({val_1, val_2, val_3}, equal_to(value)))`

Comment: Can you use C++17?

Comment: You should just be able to drop the `std::initializer_list<T>` and write `if ({val_1, val_2, val_3} == value)`, but again, don't overload operators on types you don't own.

Comment: @Justin (1) well my original idea was to exclusively use operators (bc of how the code looks) but now, I know that this is impossible to accomplish with operators alone... I think I'll default to the ranges library. (2) unfortunately `if ({val_1, val_2, val_3} == value)` produces an error. Compiler don't understand i want to call my version of the operator.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes.

Comment: A user defined literal is a literal with a user defined suffix. A braced list is not a literal to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<class T, std::size_t N>
struct any_of:std::array<T, N> {
  #define MAKE_OPERATOR( OPERATOR ) \
    template<class U, \
      std::enable_if_t< std::is_same<void, std::void_t< \
        decltype( std::declval<T const&>() == std::declval<U const&>() ) \
      >>{}, bool> =true \
    > \
    friend bool operator OPERATOR ( any_of const& lhs, U const& rhs) { \
      return std::any_of( \
        lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), \
        [&](auto&& lhs){ return lhs OPERATOR rhs; } \
      ); \
    } \
    template<class U, \
      std::enable_if_t< std::is_same<void, std::void_t< \
        decltype( std::declval<U const&>() == std::declval<T const&>() ) \
      >>{} && !std::is_same< U, any_of >{} , bool> =true \
    > \
    friend bool operator OPERATOR ( U const& lhs, any_of const& rhs) { \
      return std::any_of( \
        rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), \
        [&](auto&& rhs){ return lhs OPERATOR rhs; } \
      ); \
    }
  MAKE_OPERATOR(==)
  MAKE_OPERATOR(!=)
  MAKE_OPERATOR(<)
  MAKE_OPERATOR(<=)
  MAKE_OPERATOR(>=)
  MAKE_OPERATOR(>)
  #undef MAKE_OPERATOR
  explicit any_of( std::array<T, N> arr):std::array<T, N>(std::move(arr)) {}
  template<class...Ts>
  explicit any_of( T t, Ts... ts ):std::array<T, N>{ std::move(t), std::move(ts)... } {}
  any_of( any_of const& )=delete;
  any_of& operator=( any_of const& )=delete;
  any_of()=delete;
};
template<class T, std::size_t N>
any_of(T(&)[N]) -> any_of<T,N>;
template<class T, class...Ts>
any_of(T, Ts...) -> any_of<T, 1+sizeof...(Ts)>;
```

test code:

```
if (any_of{1,2,3} == 2) {
    std::cout << "2 is there\n";
}
if (! (any_of{1,2,3} == 7) ){
    std::cout << "7 is not there\n";
}

if (any_of{1,2,3} == any_of{5,6,1}) {
    std::cout << "overlap!\n";
}
if (!(any_of{1,2,3} == any_of{5,6,7})) {
    std::cout << "no overlap!\n";
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/636d032b1f1bf29d).

Output in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) compiler:

> ```
> 2 is there
> 7 is not there
> overlap!
> no overlap!
> ```

The various comparison operators are all supported.

Cross-type double any_of, like:

```
any_of{1,2,3} == any_of{3.14, 5.7, 1.0}
```

will fail to compile because both `==` of both `any_of` work.

Comment: this hits the spot.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make a user defined literal for a `std::initializer_list`.  Luckily though C++17 gives a new really cool tool that will help us out.  [Class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) allows us to just use the name of a class template, and the compiler will figure out what the template parameters need to be so we don't have to specify them.  This means you could leverage `std::array` and your code would become

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
bool operator==(std::array<T, N> const & list, T const & ref)
{
    for(auto const& e : list)
        if (e != ref)
            return false;
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    using std::array;
    if (array{4,4,4,4,4} == 4)
        std::cout << "all 4";
}
```

And besides the using statement it is only an extra character between `_lit` and `array`

Comment: Don't overload operators of a type outside that type's namespace, it results in surprising and annoying behavior.  And don't inject operators into `namespace std`, because that makes your program ill-formed.  In short, don't overload operators on `std` templates.  And fix your example not to be code smell.  :)

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont and if i were to create a "tag" class with a private member `std::array<T, N> _list`, a constructor: `tag(std::array<T, N> const & list) : _list(std::move(list)) {}` and a befreineded, overloaded `bool operator==(std::array<T, N> const & list, T const & ref)` ?? Would that solve the "ill-formated program" issue? the end result would look like this: `if (tag{4,4,4,4,4} == 4) {/* .... */}`

Comment: (2) sorry, I made a mistake, with a tag class, the operator should look like this:
`friend bool operator==(tag<T, N> const & list, T const & ref);` not like the one i posted above.

Comment: @cukier9a7b5 I'd just inherit from `std::array` myself.  Makes the begin/end stuff just work.

Answer (score 1):

From comment:

> @NathanOliver I am trying to "expand" current C++ syntax (it's a fun
>   little project...) The main idea is to simplify this: if ((val_1 ==
>   value) && (val_2 == value) && (val_3 == value)) into this: if
>   (std::initializer_list{val_1, val_2, val_3} == value) (ofc with an
>   overloaded operator: bool operator==(std::initializer_list const &
>   list, T const & ref))... I want to ommit the part in which i need to
>   type std::initializer_list and i figured out that i can change it
>   into a custom-literal

So looks like you need something like this:

```
template<typename T>
bool allEqualTo(T a, T b)
{
    return a == b;
}

template<typename T, typename... TArgs>
bool allEqualTo(T a, T b, TArgs... args)
{
    return allEqualTo(a, b) && allEqualTo(a, args...);
}

if (allEqualTo(value, val_1, val_2, val_3)) {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use a ranges library, you can just use `all_of`:

```
// Using Range-v3: https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/index.html
if (ranges::v3::all_of({val_1, val_2, val_3},
    [value](auto const& other) { return value == other; })) {
    // ...
}
```

You can use a helper to simplify it further:

```
// Note: Prior to C++17, this could lead to ODR violations.
// After C++17, this will be an inline variable, thus this is fine.
// If using in C++14 or before, write std::equal_to<>{} instead of std::equal_to{}.
constexpr auto equal_to = boost::hof::partial(std::equal_to{});

// ...

if (ranges::v3::all_of({val1, val_2, val_3}, equal_to(value))) {
    // ...
}
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nMdTTpA83LEMT944)

Comment: for some reason, I always forget how useful a boost is. Thank you.